# Older version of Panda, Groupby agg(list) does not work

Tags: python, pandas

Unfortunately for work the version of Python and its libraries are outdated. I am stuck on a groupby aggregation problem which I hope someone can help me with.

I have the following df

```
    Type            Cost
0   Food - Type A   1.50
1   Food - Type B   2.20
2   Car - Type A    1.30
3   Car - Type B    2.40
4   Car - Type C    3.70
```

I want create a category variable that I eventually want to group this df under.

```
category = df['Type'].str.split(' -', expand=True)[0]

0 Food
1 Food
2 Car
3 Car
4 Car
```

I then group this and turn each row into a list like this.

```
    dict= df.groupby(category).agg(list)
    
    0        Type                             Cost     
    Food    [Food - Type A, Food - Type B]             [1.5, 2.2]
    Car     [Car - Type A, Car - Type B, Car - Type C] [1,3, 2.4, 3.7]
```

Now this works normally. But the pandas I have to work with is version 0.16.2. And the agg(list) doesn't work. Perhaps it wasn't introduced yet, but I wasn't clear on the documentation.

Can someone advise how I may be able to recreate this?

Comment: Pandas 0.16 is **seven years old!** Is there really no way to use a more recent version?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: You may want to get in touch with your IT service. Not only because it could be useful to upgrade pandas but also and mainly because it means your systems are most probably exposed to many known vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it using [pandas.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table), which, it seems, was already possible with Pandas 0.16 according to the documentation:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Type": [
            "Food - Type A",
            "Food - Type B",
            "Car - Type A",
            "Car - Type B",
            "Car - Type C",
        ],
        "Cost": [1.5, 2.2, 1.3, 2.4, 3.7],
    }
)
```

```py
df["Category"] = df["Type"].str.split(" -", expand=True)[0]

df = df.pivot_table(values=["Type", "Cost"], index="Category", aggfunc=list)
```

```py
                     Cost                                        Type
Category
Car       [1.3, 2.4, 3.7]  [Car - Type A, Car - Type B, Car - Type C]
Food           [1.5, 2.2]              [Food - Type A, Food - Type B]
```